# Calculator by JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.calculator-body{
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.calculator-monitor{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.09);
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align-last: right;
 padding: 10px;
}

.btn{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 2px 1px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>cALCULATOR</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 bg main-block" id="mainBlock">
    <div class="calculator-body">
     <div class="row calculator-screen-row">
      <input type="text" name="" class="calculator-monitor" placeholder="0">
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="7">7</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="8">8</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="9">9</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">/</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="4">4</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="6">6</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">x</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="2">2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="3">3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">-</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="0">0</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">.</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">+</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">=</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone, Actually I am new in coding and especially in JS. 
Now I need to make a simple calculator with several operations.
I have tried several ways but none of them was right. 
I need to onclick of some of the numbers, the value of input was changed to the value of button (number). 
How can I manage it, I will be glad to see the answer by using jQuery.

Comment: http://codepen.io/simonja2/pen/QbGYbR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you set on the monitor the numbers you press, the operation will be elaborated later, but that is how it should work:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.number-button').click(function(data){
    var temp =  $('.calculator-monitor').val();
    $('.calculator-monitor').val(temp + $(this).attr("value"));
  });
});
```

```css
.calculator-body{
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.calculator-monitor{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.09);
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align-last: right;
 padding: 10px;
}

.btn{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 2px 1px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>cALCULATOR</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 bg main-block" id="mainBlock">
    <div class="calculator-body">
     <div class="row calculator-screen-row">
      <input type="text" name="" class="calculator-monitor" placeholder="0">
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="7">7</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="8">8</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="9">9</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">/</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="4">4</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="6">6</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">x</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="2">2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="3">3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">-</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="0">0</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">.</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">+</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">=</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.calculator-button').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        $('.calculator-monitor').val(val);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
 $('.calculator-monitor').val($( this ).text());
});
```

**Note** : Code must be inside document.ready.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added an inline script tag here where you can see that I get the value of the button using an on click event, then get the screen value defaulted to 0. I then append the number onto the computer screen.

Hope that helps! (This is my first ever SO Answer!)

```css
.calculator-body{
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.calculator-monitor{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.09);
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align-last: right;
 padding: 10px;
}

.btn{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 2px 1px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>cALCULATOR</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 bg main-block" id="mainBlock">
    <div class="calculator-body">
     <div class="row calculator-screen-row">
      <input type="text" name="" class="calculator-monitor" placeholder="0">
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="7">7</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="8">8</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="9">9</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">/</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="4">4</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="6">6</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">x</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="2">2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="3">3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">-</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="0">0</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">.</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">+</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">=</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.calculator-button').click(function(){
            var btnVal = $(this).text();
            var currentScreen = $('.calculator-monitor').val();
            if (!currentScreen || currentScreen == "") {
                currentScreen = '';
            }
            $('.calculator-monitor').val(currentScreen+''+btnVal);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arry = [];
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("number-button");
for(i = 0 ;i < elem.length ; i++)
  {
    elem[i].addEventListener("click" , function(){
      //alert(this.value);
      //document.getElementById("opscreen").value = this.value;
      arry = arry + this.value;
      document.getElementById("opscreen").value = arry;
     
   });
    var operatr = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
    button");
for(i = 0 ;i < elem.length ; i++)
  {
    elem[i].addEventListener("click" , function(){
      //alert(this.value);
      //document.getElementById("opscreen").value = this.value;
      arry = arry + this.value;
      document.getElementById("opscreen").value = arry;
     
   });
    
                             }
```

```css
.calculator-body{
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.calculator-monitor{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.09);
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align-last: right;
 padding: 10px;
}

.btn{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 2px 1px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>cALCULATOR</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 bg main-block" id="mainBlock">
    <div class="calculator-body">
     <div class="row calculator-screen-row">
      <input type="text" name="" class="calculator-monitor" placeholder="0" id="opscreen">
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="7">7</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="8">8</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="9">9</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">/</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="4">4</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="6">6</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button operator">x</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="2">2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="3">3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">-</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row buttons-row first-buttons-row">
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button number-button" value="0">0</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">.</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">+</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default calculator-button">=</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```